# Why does REST request give me a HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error?

Tags: java, rest, soap, netbeans

I deployed and ran the code from NetbeansMy ApplicationConfig.java file. When I tried to see the result at http://rasmus:8080/FinalFlightWebService/webresources/Flights/?token=salajane It gave me a 500 internal server error.

```
@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
    try {
        Class jsonProvider = Class.forName("org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature");
        resources.add(jsonProvider);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    addRestResourceClasses(resources);
    return resources;

}
private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
    resources.add(ee.ttu.idu0075.FlightsResource.class);
}
```

My REST java file

```
/**
 * Creates a new instance of FlightsResource
 */
public FlightsResource() {
}

/**
 * Retrieves representation of an instance of ee.ttu.idu0075.FlightsResource
 *
 * @param token
 * @return an instance of ee.ttu.idu0075._2015.ws.invoice.FlightType
 */
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public GetFlightListResponse getFlightList(@QueryParam("token") String token) {
    FinalFlightWebService fws = new FinalFlightWebService();
    GetFlightListRequest request = new GetFlightListRequest();
    request.setToken(token);
    return fws.getFlightList(request);
}

@GET
@Path("{id: \\d+}") //supports digits only
@Produces("application/json")
public TicketType getTicket(@PathParam("id") String id, @QueryParam("token") String token) {
    FinalFlightWebService fws = new FinalFlightWebService();
    GetTicketRequest request = new GetTicketRequest();
    request.setId(BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(id)));
    request.setToken(token);
    return fws.getTicket(request);
}
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
public void putJson(FlightType content) {
}
```

Does anyone know what I need to change to not get the HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error?

Comment: You should do some debugging.  What did you see in your server log output?

Comment: Have a look at your server log files. One thing that may be the problem is that your resource `FlightsResource` does not have any (default) `@PATH` notation so at least the method annotated with `@PUT` does not know to which path it belongs.

Comment: I have the path notation before the method where it was defaultly. The log doesnt give me an error. Just when I run the REST address, it gives me a 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR. debugger console gave me Attaching to localhost:9009
User program running.

Answer (score 0):

Added this to end and everything worked:

```
@Provider
public class DebugExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        return Response.serverError().entity(exception.getMessage()).build();
    } 
}
```